# Dropbox startup error

Tags: xubuntu, nautilus, xfce, startup, dropbox

I have downloaded and installed dropbox (following [the official instructions](https://www.dropbox.com/it/install-linux)) and then I have installed nautilus-dropbox.

I'm using XFCE (Xubuntu) and the startup of dropbox fails: icon missing in the notification area and I can't click on it.

So I've found a "solution" that is launch dropbox with:

```
dbus-launch dropbox start
```

So in the "Session and Startup" setting in XFCE I edit the line of dropbox from:

```
dropbox start -i
```

to:

```
dbus-launch dropbox start
```

But when I reboot anything is changed.

This is very strange for me. Moreover also if I delete the row of dropbox in "Session and Startup" after a reboot there is still an entry of dropbox with "dropbox start -i"

**Workaround**:
I found a "solution". I found the *.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop* file. I tried to change it with the correct startup string "*dbus-launch dropbox start*" but after every reboot the file reverts to the original and incorrect version. So I changed it and after that I changed its permissions to 0444.
It seems to work.

Comment: Disable the one with -i and add your own entry with your command of dbus

Comment: Very strange behaviour, I have added my entry and now seems to be ok. BUT if even I have disabled the "original" dropbox entry, after a reboot that entry was enabled again. Ironically now dropbox starts in a good manner but I can't disable it (except if I uninstall it) because I can delete my entry but I cant delete or even disable the original entry.

Comment: you should try to uncheck the start up at login from the Dropbox settings. Probably that should explain why you are not able to disable the original one. You could just say Dropbox settings not to auto start and retain only your command in the startup list. That should provide the releif...

Comment: Realy really strange. I tried to disable startup in Dropbox settings. Nothing has changed. Moreover I tried both to delete $HOME/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop and to do "sudo dropbox autostart n". Once again, nothing changed! Furthermore I tried to install Xubuntu on a VM and I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what version of Xubuntu you're using. However completely remove the dropbox apps using-

```
sudo apt purge dropbox nautilus-dropbox
```

command. Then either install the deb package from the website or install the nautilus-dropbox package (`sudo apt install nautilus-dropbox`) from repository. After installation, when prompted, start the Dropbox app (Select the Start option and a faulty Dropbox icon shold appear on the panel).  Now-

**To make Dropbox icon work in Xubuntu:**

**On 16.04 LTS-**
Open the Terminal and run-

```
sudo mousepad /usr/bin/dropbox
```

Create a new line after the word “import os” and add the following:

os.environ['DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS'] = ""

Save the file and reboot

**On 17.04-**

Right click on the panel and go to- Panel--Panel Preferences. Select the tab “Item”. Now select the item called “Indicator Plugin” and remove it by clicking the minus (-) button. Dropbox icon should appear normally now. However removing the Indicator Plugin also removes the sound icon. To return it, open Terminal and run-

```
sudo apt install xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin
```

Then again go to Panel Preferences and select the tab “Item”. Click on the plus (+) button and select “PulseAudio Plugin” from the list, select Add. A sound icon should appear on the panel. You can move the icon to the old position by clicking the up and down button.

Additionally, you can also install the `thunar-dropbox-plugin`. It's very useful.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using 17.10 version. However this doesn't work. First of all if I remove the Indicator Plugin then also the Wicd icon disappears. Moreover without Indicator Plugin, Dropbox doesn't show at all in the tray.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. The method I described worked for me on Xubuntu 17.10(x86). You may try to- kill the dropbox app from task manager, remove the indicator plugin and then start Dropbox again from start menu. Does it help?

Comment: And please restart your pc after that. I don't have indicator plugin on my panel but the Wicd icon is still there. :-(

Comment: No solution yet! If I remove kill dropbox, remove the indicator plugin and then reboot, I have nothing in my tray (neither dropbox nor wicd). However I found a "solution", better a "workaround". First post updated.

Comment: What is "remove kill"? However happy to hear that your problem has been solved. Congratulation!

Comment: Excuse me, tipyng error. I meant "If i kill dropbox...".

Comment: I would like to say that this does not work in Xubuntu 17.10 (confirming @siv-lab) . I posted a new question (https://askubuntu.com/questions/998785/xubuntu-dropbox-icon-fails-again-after-upgrade-to-17-10) in case someone else sees this.

Comment: Just to say that the environ trick worked for me on Xubuntu 16.04. Thanks!